# Spring Data Cassandra - using CqlOperations to run arbitrary CQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, integration-testing

Not sure whether anything changed with the `2.0` release, but this code will no longer work in a Spring Boot test, when using Spring Data Cassandra 2.0.5:

```
@Autowired
CqlTemplate cqlTemplate;
```

This was presented in a tutorial, and it's not really straightforward how to get a `CqlOperations` (the interface `CqlTemplate` implements) reading either the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#cassandra.cql-template) or the [Reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/CqlTemplate.html).

Using that annotation in a `SpringBootTest` will cause this:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
'com.alertavert.api.TriggerRestControllerTest': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through field 'cqlTemplate';
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution was pretty straightforward, but I am posting it here as I wasted some time Googling for it, which did not yield anything of value (and quite a lot of stuff that just made matters worse).

You can autowire a bean of `CassandraTemplate` and then use it to obtain the `CassandraOperation` object to execute a CQL query:

```
@Autowired
private CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;
```

and in your test:

```
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    Insert insertBuilder = QueryBuilder.insertInto("triggers")
      .value("trigger_id", id)
      .value("serializedpb", ByteBuffer.wrap("Definitely not a Protobuf".getBytes()));

    cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().execute(insertBuilder);
```

Hope this saves some folk's time!